# Automatic row grouping by day breaks group between 00:00 and 01:00 hours. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've got this sheet where on column A I've got only dates with hours, minutes and seconds. Each hour or so, depending on the time-driven trigger configuration, a new row will be recorded to LOG sheet with new data, including present date and time.

I've got this script which is executed together with the recording function. This script is supposed to automatically group rows. Each time a new row is recorded it will compare the last 2 rows to see if day as changed. If it did it will group all the rows belonging to the previous day. The same will be done for months and years.

It is working ok. Problem now is this script seems to be breaking the day group in 2 groups. This seems to be happening just for when there are rows with time between midnight and 1 am. I can't really understand why it does this. It does not to this with any other time frames. Check screen pics:

[image]

[image]

So this is the code I'm running for the grouping function:

```
const logSheetName = "LOG";

// Functions to group by day, month and year. Within each the variables are redefined, except logSheetName

// Grouping by Day
function groupDays() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetName);
    // Variables needed to get row number of the first row of row block for last day, for rowStart variable
    var dateDay = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
    var getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
    var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(getDayMonthYear).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
    var firstRowOfDay = cells[0];
    var testes = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
    // Variables needed for Grouping Function
    rowStart = firstRowOfDay;
    rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    // Group by day execution
    groupDates(dates, 'date');
    // Collapse group
    let groupClps = sheet.getRowGroup(firstRowOfDay, 1);
    // groupClps.collapse();
    // Console log
    console.log("groupDays() executed");
    console.log("first row from Days position is " + rowStart);
    console.log(getDayMonthYear);
    console.log(cells);
    console.log("auto timezone is: " + testes);
}

// Grouping by Month
function groupMonths() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetName);
    // Variables needed to get row number of the first row of row block for last day, for rowStart variable
    var dateMonth = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
    var getMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateMonth, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/YYYY");
    var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(getMonthYear).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
    var firstRowOfDay = cells[0];
    // Variables needed for Grouping Function
    rowStart = firstRowOfDay;
    rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    // Group by Month execution
    groupDates(dates, 'month');
    // Collapse group
    let groupClps = sheet.getRowGroup(firstRowOfDay, 1);
    groupClps.collapse();
    // Console log
    console.log("groupMonths() executed");
    console.log("first row from Months position is " + rowStart);
}

// Grouping by Year
function groupYears() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetName);
    // Variables needed to get row number of the first row of row block for last day, for rowStart variable
    var dateYear = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
    var getYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateYear, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY");
    var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(getYear).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
    var firstRowOfDay = cells[0];
    // Variables needed for Grouping Function
    rowStart = firstRowOfDay;
    rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    // Group by Year execution
    groupDates(dates, 'year');
    // Collapse group
    let groupClps = sheet.getRowGroup(firstRowOfDay, 1);
    groupClps.collapse();
    // Console log
    console.log("groupYears() executed");
    console.log("first row from Years position is " + rowStart);
}


var rowStart;
var rows;
var dates;
var prevDate;
var rangeStart;
var rangeEnd;
var groupingPeriod;

function groupDates(dates, period) {
    groupingPeriod = period;
    dates.forEach((date, idx) => {
        if (idx === 0) {
            processInitialDate(date);
        } else {
            processDate(date, idx);
        }
    });
}

function processInitialDate(date) {
    prevDate = date;
    rangeStart = 0;
    rangeEnd = rangeStart;
}

function processDate(date, idx) {
    if (periodHasChanged(date, prevDate, groupingPeriod)) {
        createGroup();
        rangeStart = rangeEnd + 1;
        rangeEnd = rangeStart;
    } else {
        rangeEnd++;
        if (idx === dates.length - 1) {
            createGroup();
        }
    }
    prevDate = date;
}

function periodHasChanged(currDate, prevDate, period) {
    switch (period) {
        case 'year':
            var currPeriod = currDate.getYear();
            var prevPeriod = prevDate.getYear();
            break;
        case 'month':
            var currPeriod = currDate.getMonth();
            var prevPeriod = prevDate.getMonth();
            break;
        case 'date':
            var currPeriod = currDate.getDate();
            var prevPeriod = prevDate.getDate();
            break;
    }
    return currPeriod !== prevPeriod;
}

function createGroup() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetName);
    var rangeGroup = dates.slice(rangeStart, rangeEnd + 1);
    if (rangeGroup.length > 1) {
        var range = `${rowStart + rangeStart + 1}:${rowStart + rangeEnd}`;
        sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    }
}
```

So the `console.log()`tests don't tell me anything strange is happening. The `firstRowOfDay`var tells me the right row number is targeted for the group handle. It just makes 2 groups instead of 1 and the 1st is always between 00:00 and 01:00.
Am I missing something?

Here's the dummy file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Funny, the error disappears (?) as soon as I add `.map(d => new Date()` (nonsense) to the line `dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();` --> `dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat().map(d => new Date());`. It's probably wrong way, but you can try it. But I still belive there is some mess with time zones in the script. At some place you're getting GMT+1 instead of GMT+0.

Comment: `.map(d => new Date()`
That solved it!  Thanks again man! I didn't even need to change the Timezone part. I will check later your script down bellow if it makes sense to use it instead of the one I have running. 
So what does `.map(d => new Date()` do? It maps the dates? I'll check later Javscript dicctionary. I'm at work now. Thanks =)

Comment: It does nonsense, as I said. It puts inside of all elements of the array today's date. It works, probably (I'm not sure), because the real dates aren't matter in this part of the code. All cells already sorted, numbered, and grouped. But they should contain dates because... well, let face it, because the code is rather strange and redundant.

Comment: This last comment were you replying to the `.map(d => new Date()` thing or to the comment below where I mentioned your group Function code groups either date formats? I'm sorry for the confusion I'm at newbie level when it comes to conding. Just trying to put info in the right boxes.

Comment: `Array.map(d => new Date()` fills the Array (every it's element) with nothing but current date. It's nonsense. But it works. The only reason to do this is because at the some place the script reads contents of the array and it wants that it should be dates. But it reads the dates with wrong time zone somehow. And actually it doesn't even need the dates. Something like this. Sorry for my sloppy English by the way. And for my typos. I'm on smartphone now )

Comment: No worries that was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error has to do with time zone. Try to add the line:

```
var timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
```

And use the `timeZone` variable whenever you try to make `Date` objects.

At least it worked for me. The function `groupDays()` in your script doesn't work for me somehow. I tried it but in vain. So I took my old variant from your "ARCHIVE.gs", tweaked it a bit, chaged the `timeZone` definition, and it works fine, as far as I can tell:

```
// group rows by years
function group_by_years() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  get_rows_array().forEach(y => shift_rows(y.map(m => m.flat()).flat(),sheet));
}

// group rows by months
function group_by_months() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  get_rows_array().flat().forEach(m => shift_rows(m.flat(),sheet));
}

// group rows by days
function group_by_days() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  get_rows_array().flat().flat().forEach(d => shift_rows(d.flat(),sheet))
}

function get_rows_array() {
  // var timeZone = "GMT+1";
  var timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowStart = 5;
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
  var values = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
  var o = {};

  // make the object {'year': { 'month':[days] } }
  values.forEach((date, i) => {
      var [y, m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "yyyy,MM,dd").split(",");
      // console.log(y, m, d);
      if (!o[y]) o[y] = {};
      if (!o[y][m]) o[y][m] = {};
      if (!o[y][m][d]) o[y][m][d] = [];
      o[y][m][d].push(rowStart + i);
  });
  
  // convert the unordered object {year:{month:[days]}}
  // into the ordered 3d-array [year[month[days]]]
  const numsort = (a,b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
  return Object.keys(o).sort(numsort)
    .map(y => Object.keys(o[y]).sort(numsort)
    .map(m => Object.values(o[y][m]).sort(numsort)));
}

function shift_rows(rows,sheet) {
  if (rows.length === 1) return;
  var range = `${ rows[1] }:${ rows.slice(-1) }`;
  sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice your code groups the rows either if the dates are in USA format or EURO format. Would like to have that. Need to understand how that works.

Comment: Basically it makes the array [year1 [month1 [days], month2 [days]], year2 [month1 [days] ... ] ... ]   and then makes groups from all days of the year, or all days of the month. Etc

Comment: Ok cool. Well my problem is solved. I will choose the right answer the one above this. But this code I will try to combine with my needs like the part on the one I got running which will get the row number for the first row of a block of rows of a specific day so the grouping starts from there. On the code I am using I needed to re-declare variables withing functions ´groupDay()` `groupMonth` `groupYear` life for ex. `var=rowStart`. I tried with yours but for some reason it needs to be declared outside of the grouping functions? I need to look at this later.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your goal. Probably you could add the argument to the function `function get_rows_array(rowStart)` and to call the function with this argument `get_rows_array(5).flat().forEach(...` (to start groupping from row 5). Of course you have to remove the line `var rowStart = 5;` from the function in this case

Comment: Its like I want a way to make the grouping function to automatically group rows as days and months and years are passing by. So I need the variable `rowStart` to change dynamically so it goes forward and equals the first row of the block of rows of the last day that passed. So that variable cannot remain fixed at number 5. I achieved that with the script I am running by using a way to get all the row numbers for the day that passed and put them in an array then get position `[0]` and that value will be my `rowStart` for the group funcrion. I will try that with your code.

Comment: I replied to my question so you can see some tweak I made to your code so the automatic grouping works. Your code just like you wrote it works for any date format it seems but after I tweak it for auto-groups it only works for EU date format.

Answer (score 1):

As an quick dirty patch you can try to replace in your functions `groupDays()` this line :

```
dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
```

with this:

```
dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getDisplayValues().flat(); // get strings
const eu_to_us = d => d.replace(/^(\d\d\/)(\d\d\/)/, '$2/$1/');         // dd/MM --> MM/dd
dates = dates.map(d => new Date(eu_to_us(d)));                          // get US dates
```

It converts the EU dates dd/MM/YYYY into US dates MM/dd/YYYY, and it does the trick. It seems so. Probably it fixes time zone along the way. But it's not a solid solution by any measure. It's jus a patch. I can't guarantee anything.

I believe it's a wrong idea to consider these strings as proper dates in this case. You can search, sort and group them as strings. As soon as you convert them into dates you get the mess with time zones and date formats. Imho.

Comment: The patch isn't working for me. There is some errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Jow.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yjxK.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/clMyK.png

Comment: make sure that you're using `.getDisplayValues()`.

Comment: Oh it works if I used your first suggestion in combination with this: `dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat().map(d => new Date());`

Comment: Yeah it works both ways with or without `.getDisplayValues()` if I use `map(d => new Date()`

Comment: Oh no actually it only works with `dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getDisplayValues().flat();`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the part for the date format issue:

```
// group rows by days
function group_by_days2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
  // Tweak to get the number of first row of block of rows of previous day + tweak for date format US/EU etc
  var dateDay = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
  // Conditional variable for US and EU date formats, changes according to locale on spreadsheet settings. Also forces date format.
  var locale = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale();
  var getDayMonthYear;
  switch (locale) {
  case 'en_US', 'en_CA', 'en_ZA':
  sheet.getRange("A5:A").setNumberFormat('m"/"d"/"yyyy" "h":"mm":"ss');
  getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/YYYY");
  console.log("no locale detected");
  break;
  case 'zh_CN', 'hu_HU', 'lt_LT':
  sheet.getRange("A5:A").setNumberFormat('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd" "hh":"mm":"ss'); 
  getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd");
  break;
  default:
  sheet.getRange("A5:A").setNumberFormat('dd"/"mm"/"yyyy" "hh":"mm":"ss');
  getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
  console.log("no locale detected");
}
  // 2nd part of tweat for getting the number of first row of block of rows of previous day
  var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(getDayMonthYear).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
  var firstRowOfDay = cells[0];
  // Variables needed for Grouping Function
  rowStart = firstRowOfDay;
  get_rows_array2().flat().flat().forEach(d => shift_rows2(d.flat(),sheet))
}
```

Comment: Also now I need to find a way to make this work with other date formats. Like if the user is chinese the date is something else: `2021-9-9 上午02:39:48`. This will make the code too long and ugly. But it will work.

Comment: Solved the China thing. Just made 2 cases 1 for US etc other for China etc, everything else default.

Answer (score 0):

I realized something. The main sheet I am working on will be used by lets say 60% of people from US the rest 40% rest of the world. So if the dates are in US format this code won't work. I need something that will work either the User is in US Date format or EU or other. Your code for grouping rows does the job for any date format it seems. Problem is after I tweak your code for using with automatic grouping it displays an error: `Exception: The parameters (null,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.` Problem is with my tweak.
So below is just the `group_by_days()` with my tweak:

```
function group_by_days() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
  // Variables needed to get row number of the first row of row block for last day, for rowStart variable
  var dateDay = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
  var getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
  var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(getDayMonthYear).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
  var firstRowOfDay = cells[0];
  // Variables needed for Grouping Function
  rowStart = firstRowOfDay;
  get_rows_array().flat().flat().forEach(d => shift_rows(d.flat(),sheet))
}

var rowStart;
```

The variable `rowStart` I declared it outside any function so I can call it within each function with different values.

So the problem might be with this line:

```
var getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
```

Is there a way to make this combine with either US or any other date formats?

Full code at:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yep. Change the line with this: `var getDayMonthYear = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/YYYY")` Using the tool "TextFinder" has its own problems. You need to be sure that format dates in your script always matched with the search pattern. In this case dates in script looks like `M/d/YYYY`. But search pattern was `dd/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: First screenshot is yesterday's sheet, second shot from today's sheet:  https://i.imgur.com/nkudFYb.png You need to be extremely careful when you're dealing with dates.

Comment: If I use `M/d/YYYY` it will search for US format right? Is there a way to declare a variable conditionally? Like: `detect spreadSheet date format -> if US format = M/d/YYYY, else = dd/MM/YYYY`. I will see if something like this is possible. That way I wouldn't have to worry about date user's date format. If I can't find a way I'll post another question.

Comment: I'd advice to grab all dates from a sheet as Data objects and then you can format them in your script more or less independently from original format on the sheet. But if you're using TextFinder the matter becomes more complicated. I think it's a good idea to ask if it's possible (and how?) to use TextFinder if you have dates with different formating (ISO, US, UK... etc). Since I have no ready answer.

Comment: I think I found a way. I used `switch`statement which is sort of a way to declare conditional variable. I replied to my question with the code. It works. It will fetch the Locale defined in spreadsheet settings then it will use the US date formate if `locale = en_US` or EU format if for ex.: `locale = en_GB`. It will also force format the entire column for the correct date format if for any reason the user chose US as locale but as the dates in EU format, or vice versa. Anyway this way the sheet will never create an error, even if the guy set the locale wrong. At least I hope so.